# Waiting for DeleteForgeAppAsync to proceed

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am using the Forge .NET SDK. To clear all appbundles and activities under my Forge App account I call :

```
        await _designAutomation.DeleteForgeAppAsync("me");
```

Right afterwards I need to (re)create a new nickname for my Forge App then (re)create the needed AppBundle and Activity :

```
        await _designAutomation.ForgeAppsApi.CreateNicknameAsync("me", new NicknameRecord { Nickname = NICKNAME });
        await EnsureAppBundle();
        await EnsureActivity();
```

Quite often one of three calls above fails because the Forge App is still being deleted, so for instance there is a conflict for the nickname creation, or the AppBundle/Activity cannot be created.

The Forge documentation at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-DELETE/ says : *This may take up to 2 minutes. During this time the app will not be able to make successful requests.*

Would not the asynchronous call to DeleteForgeAppAsync have to wait for the deletion to be complete ?

Thanks for your help.

Maxime

Comment: as soon as `await _designAutomation.DeleteForgeAppAsync("me");` receives a response (ie`204 ok`) it will return. Usually a 204 means the requested has been fullfilled by the server so theres something fishy going on. You are getting a 204 as a response to `await _designAutomation.DeleteForgeAppAsync("me");` right ?

Comment: Yes, I receive a 204 response. But I think the .NET SDK should provide a function to wait for complete deletion. Otherwise how are we supposed to know when we can try to create nicknames, appbundles, ... in the cleared Forge App ?

Comment: The forge .net sdk simply makes the calls to the endpoints as per https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/Http/ForgeAppsApi.gen.cs So yes it would be nice to have an endpoint that checks this job for completion

Comment: All endpoints check for the completion of this and return 409 "Forge App is being deleted.". You can use this to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this scenario by doing retries on 409 response following a forge app deletion.
If you want to add more logic around 409 retries you could always also inspect the body.

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-DELETE/) you’d need to wait a few for the delete action to take effect despite the SDK  API appears to be synchronous:

> This may take up to 2 minutes. During this time the app will not be able to make successful requests.

Comment: I know, that documentation quote was in my initial post... Wait "a few"? What amount of time is it?